# How to use dynamic_rnn with LSTM cell and embeddings with 3D Input?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to create a neural network with an architecture: input -> embeddings -> LSTM -> output. However, I am getting an error from the LSTM cell saying:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RNN.py", line 192, in <module>
    dtype=tf.float32)
  File "anaconda2-4.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 598, in dynamic_rnn
    dtype=dtype)
  File "anaconda2-4.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 761, in _dynamic_rnn_loop
    swap_memory=swap_memory)
  File "anaconda2-4.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2775, in while_loop
    result = context.BuildLoop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "anaconda2-4.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2604, in BuildLoop
    pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "anaconda2-4.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2554, in _BuildLoop
    body_result = body(*packed_vars_for_body)
  File "anaconda2-4.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 744, in _time_step
    skip_conditionals=True)
  File "anaconda2-4.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 236, in _rnn_step
    new_output, new_state = call_cell()
  File "anaconda2-4.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 732, in <lambda>
    call_cell = lambda: cell(input_t, state)
  File "anaconda2-4.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 180, in __call__
    return super(RNNCell, self).__call__(inputs, state)
  File "anaconda2-4.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 450, in __call__
    outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "anaconda2-4.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/core_rnn_cell.py", line 226, in call
    output, res_state = self._cell(inputs, state)
  File "anaconda2-4.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 180, in __call__
    return super(RNNCell, self).__call__(inputs, state)
  File "anaconda2-4.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 450, in __call__
    outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "anaconda2-4.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 938, in call
    cur_inp, new_state = cell(cur_inp, cur_state)
  File "anaconda2-4.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 774, in __call__
    output, new_state = self._cell(inputs, state, scope)
  File "anaconda2-4.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 180, in __call__
    return super(RNNCell, self).__call__(inputs, state)
  File "anaconda2-4.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 450, in __call__
    outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "anaconda2-4.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 554, in call
    input_size = inputs.get_shape().with_rank(2)[1]
  File "anaconda2-4.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 637, in with_rank
    raise ValueError("Shape %s must have rank %d" % (self, rank))
ValueError: Shape (9, 600, 256) must have rank 2
```

500 is the `vocabsize` in the below code. `word_embedding_size` is 256. `batch_size` is 9.

Here is the model I have built:

```py
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, maxlength, vocabsize])
lengths = tf.placeholders(tf.int32, [batch_size])
embeddings = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([vocabsize, word_embedding_size], -1, 1)

lstm = {}
lstm[0] = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(hidden_layer_size, state_is_tuple=True, initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed=random_seed))
lstm[0] = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm[0], output_keep_prob=0.5)
lstm[0] = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(cells=[lstm[0]] * 1, state_is_tuple=True)
output_layer = {}
output_layer[0] = Layer.W(1 * hidden_layer_size, 20, 'OutputLayer')
output_bias = {}
output_bias[0] = Layer.b(20, 'OutputBias')
outputs = {}
fstate = {}

rnn_inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, inputs)

with tf.variable_scope("lstm0"):
    # create the rnn graph at run time
    outputs[0], fstate[0] = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm[0], run_inputs,
                                          sequence_length=lengths, 
                                          dtype=tf.float32)
logits = {}
logits[0] = tf.matmul(tf.concat([f.h for f in fstate[0]], 1), output_layer[0]) + output_bias[0]
loss = {}
result = refblock = tf.nn.softmax(logits[0])
```

I don't understand what the error is, because I thought `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` was supposed to handle my 3D input and pass it to the LSTM cell in the appropriate format, but seems like it is not working, and I don't understand why.

If anyone could help me with what the problem is, that would be great!

Thanks

Comment: I think the problem may be something to do with the embeddings. Still haven't figured it out though.

Comment: Can you post the entire error traceback?

Comment: Just updated the post with the entire error message. The line is where I call `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`

Comment: @Engineero I noticed you deleted your answer, were you unable to figure this out? If so, that's fine, I found a way around it.